# Need HTTPS on web server with plesk. Without buying certificate?

Tags: web-hosting, https, security-certificate, free, plesk

I just want that communication with web server is encrypted. I don't want to by SSL certificate.

The server has Plesk installed and as i see, there is some way to add SSL certificate but i don't know how to generate free one which will force domain.com/something to be connected via SSL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a self-signed certificate in this case. If you are using a shared IP, you will still have to purchase a dedicated IP for your website.

Self-signed certificates can be used but the problem with them is that your visitors will see a warning regarding the website while browsing the website.

Personally, I would suggest you to get an SSL Certificate.

Please check [MediaTemple SSL cert information](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1633/Creating+and+installing+a+free+self-signed+SSL+Certificate) for more details on self-signed certificates.

Comment: Ok, how to generate self signed cert?

Comment: Please check the url that I have mentioned.
goo.gl/zReYP

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple to generate self signed certificate..here is the forum post citing this details

http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?33510-How-to-Create-Self-signed-SSL-Certificate-for-Dummies

> It's simple. Log in as the admin, go to "server", then "certificate". Fill in the information and press "self signed". Then you should wait a minute or so and tada .. you have your own self signed certificate ready and installed on your Plesk server.

You must know that Selfsigned SSL is not as effective as SSL issued by CA. If price is the matter, you can always have option to buy SSL from their reselling partners.

Comment: I already did that, it works now. I force certain pages to be redirected to https and that is ok. But i wish i know more about certs. I don't like to be tied to plesk at all :D thx anyway :)